# Parse bash variable for command and command options

Tags: bash, shell, variables

Input variable contains:

```
key1-key2-key3_command
```

Output needs to be:

```
command -k key1 -k key2 -k key3
```

Caveat: Number of keys can vary from 1 to 3.

I've counted the number of dashes and use that with an if statement to create a Boolean indicator for each key (ie. key1=1, unset key2). Then I was going to use something like `${parameter:+word}` to add in the key if the flag for that key is set. It started getting a bit messy so I thought I'd ask here on what the best way to achieve this would be.

Answer (score 5):

```
var='key1-key2-key3_command'

IFS=_ read -r  keys command <<< "$var"   # Split $var at underscores.
IFS=- read -ra keys         <<< "$keys"  # Split $keys at dashes, -a to save as array.

for key in "${keys[@]}"; do              # Treat $command as an array and add
    command+=(-k "$key")                 # -k arguments to it.
done

echo "${command[@]}"
```

Notes:

- This handles an arbitrary number of keys.
- Handles keys with whitespace in them.
- The changes to `$IFS` are only temporary; they don't affect subsequent commands.
- If you want to execute the command, change the last line to simply `"${command[@]}"` (no echo).

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "key1-key2-key3_command" | sed -r 's/(.*?)-(.*?)-(.*?)_(.*?)/\4 -k \1 -k \2 -k \3/g'
command -k key1 -k key2 -k key3
```

Answer (score 0):

Runs in a subshell to avoid polluting the current IFS and positional params

```
( 
    IFS="-_"
    set -- $var
    command=("${!#}")
    while [[ "$1" != "${command[0]}" ]]; do 
        command+=(-k "$1")
        shift
    done
    echo "${command[@]}"
)
```

Remove "echo" to execute.